# Using JQuery methods on Code Loaded From Ajax in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, tabs

I have a page that has a side panel and a center div.  When the main page loads, it fills up the side panel and makes an ajax call to get the appropriate content for the center div.  After the ajax content is loaded, I then use two jquery plugins - one for tabs, the other for forms.  In firefox and chrome, everything works well.  But, in Internet Explorer 8, I get the lovely Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
var url = '/instances/edit/' + instance_id + '/1';


$('#frame_content').load(url, function() {

    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div.pane", {history:true});
    $('#InstanceEditForm').ajaxForm(function(responseText) {

            ....

    });

});
```

I tried removing both the tabs call and the ajaxForm call and trying them individually, but they both fail.  I've noticed that if the edit page doesn't load any content at all, the tabs and ajaxForm call in the same method; so my first hunch was that it was a timing thing, and the necessary Dom elements hadn't loaded yet.  But, putting in an alert before the call to tabs doesn't help.   Is there something magical I should be doing to use jQuery calls on pages that are rendered by an ajax call?

Comment: Further testing shows that the tabs ul is loaded.  I can alert it's id right before the call to $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div.pane", {history:true}); fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many hours of work, I finally got it all sorted out.  It was a cascading number of things.

1. The javascript files for the tabs were included on the page that contained the tabs.  These include files were not getting included in IE after the ajax call.  So, the first step was to move the include files out to the main page.  Then, my tabs worked.
2. However, the form wouldn't submit.  I converted it back to a regular form, no ajax submission, and it still wouldn't work.  Further inspection showed that using the jquery.html() method to fill the div was stripping out the form tags in IE.  Furthermore, everything ABOVE the form tag was stripped out as well.  I ended up using plain old javaScript innerhtml instead.  Then, of course, the call to render the tabs promptly failed again.
3. So, the call to render the tabs, which I had moved to the page being rendered by the ajax call during previous troubleshooting had to come back out.

And, the final code looks like:

```
$('#flashMessage').css('display', 'none');
    var nav_url = '/instances/get_sections/' + instance_id;
    var stop = 0;
    $('#navigation').load(nav_url, function() {


        var url = '/instances/edit/' + instance_id + '/1';

        $.get(url, function(data) {

            document.getElementById('frame_content').innerHTML = data;
            $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div.pane", {history:true});
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap that code so it gets executed after the DOM has fully loaded:

```
$(function () {
 // Put code here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Tried that.  Also tried $(document).ready(function() {  No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are right that its because the DOM elements aren't loaded, the callback function runs as soon as the AJAX call is successful and this could happen before the page is fully loaded. Would it be possible to add these functions to the IFRAME HTML and call them with $(document).ready(function() { .. });